# How to load .mtx file in NetworkX?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, anaconda, networkx

I have a graph in Matrix Market Exchange Format (.mtx). Format details are available in https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html

I want to load the graph in NetworkX for graph analytics purpose. Could please let me know how I can load a .mtx file in NetworkX? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use scipy.io library and read the .mtx file as shown below.

```
from scipy.io import mmread
a = mmread('matname.mtx')
```

I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Codingkido is right. just load that in nx

```
from scipy.io import mmread
import networkx as nx
a = mmread('matname.mtx')
graph = nx.Graph(a)
```